# CanLoad, Lazy modules and take(1)

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I'm protecting a lazy module with a Guard using CanLoad.

I'm recovering the status of my ngrx store, and checking if the user is authenticated.

Here is my code in my auth-guard.service.ts:

```
canLoad() {
    return this.store.pipe(
        select('auth'),
        take(1),
        map(
            (authState: fromAuth.State) => {
                if (authState.authenticated) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    this.router.navigate(['/auth/signin']);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        ))
}
```

This code is OK. All works as expected.

But the question is... Why I need to use take(1) to make this works? If I remove the take(1), this guard don't works properly.

Answer (score 1):

It will only work with take(1) because without the observable wont complete at this time and canLoad waits until the observable completes.

See http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html the take will build an new observable take x items from its source and after it will complete and ignore further items.

Comment: This is correct. You can also use the [takeWhile](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/takewhile.html) operator for a conditional completion. i.e. `takeWhile(x => x <5)` will only complete when x is 5 or greater.